# Converting Object Properties Into Different View-able Objects

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inversion-of-control, ivalueconverter

say I have an object graph that looks like this (this isn't my real object):

```
CaseFile
- Sections (collection)
  - Documents (collection of type:Document)
- Other Node
  - Other Children (collection)
    - More children (collection)
```

And I want to present this data in a 'TreeView'. I'm using `HierarchicalDataTemplate`'s to manage how each child object is displayed, this works great.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="x:Type local:Document">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <Image Source="{Binding FileName, Converter="MyResourceConverter"}" />
  <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Name}" />
  </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

I want to display special icons for different objects. Here's where it gets thick: I can display static images for certain classes or types, I can even display icons based on metadata of an instantiated class. I'm using a '`IValueConverter`' to do this and it works great.

```
class MyResourseConverter : IValueConverter
{
  private static readonly IImageManager _imageManager = 
    new CachedImageManager(new SystemImageManager());


  public MyResourceConverter() // place where I'd like to inject this IImageManager
  {
  }
  //... IValueConverter Properties
  //... That uses the _imageManger
}
```

My '`IValueConverter`' had dependencies and I can't figure out how to inject those dependencies and I've searched all over to see how to fix this. The closest I've seen to fixing this is to use something like '`ServiceLocator`' inline in the class but this seems like an anti-pattern to me, it's totally defeating the purpose of the IoC in the first place.

Is there another way to get my sub-graph objects to display or '`convert`' their data into things like '`ImageSource`' without a converter?

Comment: How about having a ViewModel-version of the Document-class (or some other kind of Facade for the class)? In this class you could have a property returning an URI to the image. This property could use a injected IImageManager.

Comment: Could you use [x:Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795382.aspx) to inject the dependencies in XAML when you declare the converter?

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer: You should put that as an answer. `ServiceLocator` is the easiest way to get at the dependency but breaks SOLID - I didn't know about `x:Arguments` before you mentioned it. Nice one!

Comment: Have done, cheers. Glad it worked.

Comment: @HåkanFahlstedt I get a constructed object like the graph, I would have to deconstruct it and reconstruct with the new view models, it seems cumbersome to me.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer with x:Arguments will I be able to add complex objects, my injected class implements a decorator pattern via the constructor

Comment: I'm not sure, but if it's a problem you can always just new it up in code-behind and add it to the resources with `this.Resources.Add("MyResourceConverter", converter);` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [x:Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795382.aspx) within XAML to inject dependencies via your converter constructor.

Answer (score 0):

somewhat shameful but I'm doing something similar to 'ServiceLocator' to just roll forward:

in App.xaml.cx

```
using System.Windows;
using SimpleInjector;

public partial class App : Application
{
    private static Container container;

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough]
    public static TService GetInstance<TService>() where TService : class {
        return container.GetInstance<TService>();
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        Bootstrap();
    }

    private static void Bootstrap()  {
        // Create the container as usual.
        var container = new Container();

        // Register your types, for instance:
        container.RegisterSingle<IImageManager>(() => new CachedImageManager(new SystemImageManager()););

        // Optionally verify the container.
        container.Verify();

        // Store the container for use by the application.
        App.container = container;
    }
}
```

In the converter

```
class MyResourseConverter : IValueConverter
{
  private static readonly IImageManager _imageManager = 
    new CachedImageManager(new SystemImageManager());

  public MyResourceConverter()
  {
     _imageManager = App.GetInstance<IImageManager>();
  }

  //... IValueConverter Properties
  //... That uses the _imageManger
}
```